# Google Spreadsheet importxml() second span

Tags: html, import, spreadsheet

how I can import value from second span? Example:

```
    <div class="row-between">
        <div class="price-blue">
            <span>Price</span>
            <span>13,49 €</span>
        </div>
    <div>
```

This dont working

```
=IMPORTXML(B2;"//div[@class='price-blue']/span/span")
```

Comment: Your first div isn't closed properly.

Comment: If you fix that, it's `//div[@class='price-blue']/span[2]`

Comment: I misspelled the example, but it doesn't work that way. I try this `//div[@class='price-blue']/span[2]` but dont work.

Comment: `//div[@class='price-blue']/span[2]/text()` then?  There are a bunch of XPATH testers online that you can use to play with this.

Comment: Still same `#N/A`

Comment: OK, well the XPATH testers online say that it works.  Not sure why it's not working in your particular situation.

Comment: Test version. Look C15 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nuC7QgNRIFWI0XJWamP1v5bE4puCm7cWfShT8H2c2MQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.  Next time, include all of the information someone needs to answer your question *when you first post.*

Comment: We are getting somewhere, but result we don't have. Some idea?

Comment: Problem is, that importing data are on the page, are generated over ajax, so this data are loaded with time delay. How I can do, load data from complete loaded page? Or how import data with time delay?